# NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: json, angular, typescript, pipe, async-pipe

Being new to Angular\TS, I want to use Async Pipe to display JSON data . Following is the code with Model Interface.It compiles but gives the error in console and doesn't display anything.
I want to use the particular URL given. The error is

**Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays**

TS

```
       customerObs = this.http.get<Customer[]>('https://randomuser.me/api/?format=json');

       constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

HTML

```
           <li *ngFor="let customer of customerObs | async">
              {{customer.gender}}
           </li>
```

Interface

```
      export interface Customer {gender: string;email: string;}
```

Comment: Sounds like your server is responding with an object and not an array.

Comment: what would be the fix please?

Comment: You would need to share your http Response, if that is the case.

Comment: sorry I am confused, is it not using http service as the code says in the Typescript file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the response from the server you will see that it is returning an object and not an array:

```json
{"results":[{ ... }]}
```

#### Option 1

Option 1 would be to `map` the response by getting the `results` property of the object through a `pipe()` like this:

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs';

interface Customer { }
interface Response { results: Customer[] }

customerObs = this.http.get<Response>('https://randomuser.me/api/?format=json')
  .pipe(map(i => i.results))
```

#### Option 2

Option 2 would be to use get the results property directly in the html (along with the generics in the typescript):

```js
interface Customer { }
interface Response { results: Customer[] }

customerObs = this.http.get<Response>('https://randomuser.me/api/?format=json');
```

```html
<ul *ngIf="customerObs | async as response">
  <li *ngFor="let customer of response.results">
    {{customer.gender}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If I want to use Option 2 , it is not recognising 'results'.Says Property 'results' does not exist on type 'Customer[]' .

Comment: You need to also update the generics on `this.http.get`, see my updates.

Comment: So I have created another interface 'Response'  with  results: Customer[] ; However defintely it is wrong what I have written. I am not sure what am i missing, this seems silly from my side but being a beginner i am really lost.

Comment: the link is not working.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/looping-over-http-request?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks a lot , it has worked now. This is really helpful.